# control on TabControl tab is disabled

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tabs, mfc

**Update-3**

This is the solution: instead of using "this" which is reference to the form view, Minxin Yu suggested to replace by a pointer to the "CMFCTabCtrl m_wndTab" control. Thank you. For the code, please compare the answer I provided.

**Update-2**: It seems that the title bar of the dialog tab pages is removed for all 4 tab pages. The code I used in InitialUpdaye is:

```
m_wnd1.ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);
m_wnd2.ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);
m_wnd3.ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);
m_wnd4.ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);
```

**Update-1**: Please note that the code to remove the title is in oninitialupdate in TabControlView.cpp, the code to implement the list control is in CPPL_4(.h file and .cpp file). And last not least: Please download the code from the link provided further down: https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples/blob/master/VC2010Samples/MFC/Visual%20C%2B%2B%202008%20Feature%20Pack/TabControl/TabControlView.cpp.

Thank you.

---

I want to achieve the following:

have a tab control (CTabCtrl) and add 1 list control (CListCtrl)  on each of the tabs of the tab control.

The list controls are filled via a Database (1 table for 1 list control). Under the list controls columns are edit controls with the width of the list control's column. These are meant for editing fields of the list control.

Under the edit controls are some maneuvering button (including deleting, updating, and adding recordsets (rows in the list control) as well as move one row up/down one page up/down, etc.

As this is my first project using a tab control I used some MS code from here:

https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples/blob/master/VC2010Samples/MFC/Visual%20C%2B%2B%202008%20Feature%20Pack/TabControl/TabControlView.cpp.

The solution is old and when using it, Visual Studio is converting it to the latest version of its Visual Studio Solution. The code is working. The author of this sample program used Edit controls together with the tab control, meaning that each tabpage is an edit control. logging of actions happens in a list box, there are visual changes to the tab control via buttons.

I changed the code so that instead of using edit controls the tab pages were dialogs (I used CDialogEx).

As I found the title bar disturbing I deleted it using program code in the oninitialupdate event of the view. This was working as long as I did not add the list control to the tab pages. As soon as I did, the title was not "deletable". The list control is located on tab Four. An image is attached.

On the second tab page tab Two I added a check box.

Neither of these controls are accessible (i.e. i cannot check/uncheck the check box, no selection is showing when I try to click onto a row in the list control, there is a click event code at the end of the CCP_4.cpp file, which is never reached (i.e. a book mark is never stopping execution!).

My objective is that list control and checkbox on the tab pages 2 and 4 are accessible as well as that the title bar in tab four should vanish, as it does for the other 3 tab pages. Please help.

What I did:

I used four property pages (large) from the as my "dialog". I then created classes for each of the dialogs. for the fourth class (dialog for tab 4) I added a virtual function "OnInitialUpdate" and added list control code in there. (Please compare the third image. It contains explanations for the Add Resource Dialog as well as for the Resource dialog which shows the dialog resources used by the program)

All the other 4 classes are as produced by the class wizard.

[This is tab Four - one list control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uivY.png)

[This is tab Two - one check box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyCSz.png)

[This is where I created additional dialogs and where I created the classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtnuS.png)

[The picture control is the only control needed here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPEkJ.png)

Here is the code for tab Four (class CPPL_4) the cpp file:

```
// CPPL_4.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "pch.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TabControl.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "CPPL_4.h"


// CPPL_4 dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CPPL_4, CDialogEx)

CPPL_4::CPPL_4(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
: CDialogEx(IDD_PPL_4, pParent)
{
}

CPPL_4::~CPPL_4()
{
}

void CPPL_4::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
//DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_COLOR, m_list);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST, m_list);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CPPL_4, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_ACTIVATE()
    ON_NOTIFY(NM_CLICK, IDC_LIST, &CPPL_4::OnClickList)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CPPL_4 message handlers



BOOL CPPL_4::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    m_list.InsertColumn(0, _T("Column 1"));
    m_list.InsertColumn(1, _T("Column 2"));
    m_list.SetColumnWidth(0, 200);
    m_list.SetColumnWidth(1, 200);
    m_list.InsertItem(0, _T("   1  "));
    m_list.InsertItem(1, _T("   2  "));
    m_list.SetItemText(0, 1, "11");
    m_list.SetItemText(1, 1, "22");

    return FALSE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
    // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}


void CPPL_4::OnClickList(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
LPNMITEMACTIVATE pNMItemActivate = reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNMHDR);
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
m_list.SetFocus();
MessageBox("Got click event on list control!");
*pResult = 0;
}
```

Here is the code for tab Four (class CPPL_4) the .h file:

```
#pragma once
#include "afxdialogex.h"


// CPPL_4 dialog

class CPPL_4 : public CDialogEx
{
DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CPPL_4)

public:
    CPPL_4(CWnd* pParent = nullptr);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~CPPL_4();

// Dialog Data
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
enum { IDD = IDD_PPL_4 };
#endif

protected:
// DDX/DDV support
virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    CListCtrl m_list;
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnClickList(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult);
};
```

The other 3 tabs have everythingidentical with exception of the virtual OnInitDialog function

This is the Form view file which I updated to a minimal skelleton; it should outline my problem:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "TabControl.h"

    #include "TabControlDoc.h"
    #include "TabControlView.h"

    #ifdef _DEBUG
    #define new DEBUG_NEW
    #undef THIS_FILE
    static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
    #endif

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CTabControlView

    IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CTabControlView, CFormView)

    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTabControlView, CFormView)
        ON_WM_CONTEXTMENU()
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CTabControlView construction/destruction

    CTabControlView::CTabControlView()
        : CFormView(CTabControlView::IDD)
    {
    }

    CTabControlView::~CTabControlView()
    {
    }

    void CTabControlView::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
        {
        CFormView::DoDataExchange(pDX);
        DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TAB, m_wndTabLoc);
        //DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_STATIC_TABLOC, m_wndTabLoc);
    }

    BOOL CTabControlView::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
    {
        // TODO: Modify the Window class or styles here by 
        // modifying the CREATESTRUCT cs

        return CFormView::PreCreateWindow(cs);
    }

    void CTabControlView::OnInitialUpdate()
    {
        // There is only one view ever, so it only needs to do 
        // the initial update once--otherwise the application is  
        // resized needlessly.
        static BOOL bUpdatedOnce = FALSE;
        if (bUpdatedOnce)
            return;
        bUpdatedOnce = TRUE;

        CFormView::OnInitialUpdate();
        GetParentFrame()->RecalcLayout();

        if (m_wndTab.GetSafeHwnd () != NULL)
        {
            return;
        }

        CRect rectTab;

        m_wndTabLoc.GetWindowRect (&rectTab);
        ScreenToClient (&rectTab);

        m_wndTab.Create (CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_3D, rectTab, this, 1,
            CMFCTabCtrl::LOCATION_TOP);

        m_wnd1.Create(IDD_PPL_1, this);
        // remove title bar of dialog
        m_wnd1.ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);

        m_wnd2.Create(IDD_PPL_2, this);         
       // remove title bar of dialog
        m_wnd2.ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);

        m_wnd3.Create(IDD_PPL_3, this); 
        // remove title bar of dialog
        m_wnd3.ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);

        m_wnd4.Create(IDD_PPL_4, this);
        // remove title bar of dialog
        // This did not work out!!!!
        m_wnd4.m_list.ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);

        m_wndTab.AddTab (&m_wnd1, _T("One"), 0, FALSE);
        m_wndTab.AddTab (&m_wnd2, _T("Two"), 1, FALSE);
        m_wndTab.AddTab (&m_wnd3, _T("Three"), 2, FALSE);
        m_wndTab.AddTab (&m_wnd4, _T("Four"), 3, FALSE);

        UpdateData (FALSE);
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CTabControlView diagnostics

    #ifdef _DEBUG
    void CTabControlView::AssertValid() const
    {
        CFormView::AssertValid();
    }

    void CTabControlView::Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const
    {
        CFormView::Dump(dc);
    }

    CTabControlDoc* CTabControlView::GetDocument() // non-debug version is inline
    {
        ASSERT(m_pDocument->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CTabControlDoc)));
        return (CTabControlDoc*)m_pDocument;
    }
    #endif //_DEBUG

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CTabControlView message handlers

    void CTabControlView::OnContextMenu(CWnd*, CPoint point)
    {
        theApp.ShowPopupMenu (IDR_CONTEXT_MENU, point, this);
    }
```

**Updated TabControlView.h**

```
    #pragma once
    #include "CPPL_1.h"
    #include "CPPL_2.h"
    #include "CPPL_3.h"
    #include "CPPL_4.h"
    class CTabControlView : public CFormView
    {
    protected: // create from serialization only
        CTabControlView();
        DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CTabControlView)

    public:
        enum { IDD = IDD_TABCONTROL_FORM };

    // Attributes
    public:
        CTabControlDoc* GetDocument();

    protected:
        CMFCTabCtrl m_wndTab;

    // Operations
    public:
        CPPL_1 m_wnd1;
        CPPL_2 m_wnd2;
        CPPL_3 m_wnd3;
        CPPL_4 m_wnd4;
        // Overrides
        public:
        virtual BOOL PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);
        protected:
        virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
        virtual void OnInitialUpdate(); // called first time after construct

    // Implementation
    public:
        virtual ~CTabControlView();
    #ifdef _DEBUG
        virtual void AssertValid() const;
        virtual void Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const;
    #endif

    protected:
        //void AddNotification (LPCTSTR lpszText);

    protected:
        afx_msg void OnContextMenu(CWnd*, CPoint point);

        DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    public:
        //afx_msg void OnCbnSelchangeTabStyle();
        //afx_msg void OnStnClickedTab();
        CStatic m_wndTabLoc;
    };

    #ifndef _DEBUG  // debug version in TabControlView.cpp
    inline CTabControlDoc* CTabControlView::GetDocument()
       { return (CTabControlDoc*)m_pDocument; }
    #endif
```

**End of updated TabControlView.h file**

Comment: You need to read [mre].

Comment: "Sorry again. It is lengthy" - the problem is not the length of the code *as such*, it's that it is not a minimal example to demonstrate the problem. If you read [mre] you'll see that the point of the exercise is to create a new minimal program that contains just enough to demonstrate the problem and no more. Yes, creating such a program takes effort, but that's what is expected here. We don't want to guess or wade through mountains of code to figure out the problem for you - *you* have to do that work.

Comment: Hi Jesper, I added some docuentation into the OninitialUpdate virtual function and I think that should help to understand, that the code is "just not working". OK, I will delete all the events, not necessary for my problem.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) should be useful reading.

Comment: Hi Jesper, I heavily rely on the debugger during development and thank you for your hints. . I deleted most of my above discussions and changed my code accordingly. I hope that is satisfactory.

Comment: Why did you change the code in [`CTabControlView::OnInitialUpdate()`](https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples/blob/master/VC2010Samples/MFC/Visual%20C%2B%2B%202008%20Feature%20Pack/TabControl/TabControlView.cpp#L86-L147)? What specific problem were you trying to solve?

Comment: What the sample code did was: it added some text to the edit control, where I wanted to add controls.

Comment: I noticed that the from the CPicture control on the form the CStatic variable m_wndTabloc is created. From the code inside the view I took that obtaining the rectangle for the the tabbed control was the only purpose for this variable. When I deleted the original CPicture control from the dialog and replaced itwith another control (including a CPicture typed control) I was not able to see the tabbed control on the form view of the running applciation. Any ideas with respect to this?

Comment: I tested `m_dlg.Create(IDD_DIALOG1,  &m_wndTab); m_wndTab.AddTab (&m_dlg, _T("Four"), 3, FALSE); `  but the  control is not disabled.  `As I found the title bar disturbing ` What about setting [no border dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z3MQ.png) in properties?

Comment: Hi Minxin, that worked for me. I have all my problems resolved now. I quickly will add my new OninitialUpdate function in an Update and my problem is resolved. Thank you.

Comment: MinXin, I tried No borders for the dialog and found that the title bar was not removed.

Comment: I know, this is an extra: If I copy the CPicture control from the MS sample project to a new project having identical classes, IDs, etc then the tabbing of the control will take place. If I add a new CPicture control to the form view, it won't work. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to let you know that ***Minxin Yu*** came up with the answer and I just want to close my question, because I got everything what I asked for in the begining:

Why is there a tabbed dialog page with a title bar, though the title bar style (WS_CAPTIOM) was deleted:

The code working is:

```
         m_wnd4.ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);
```

where m_wnd4 is of type CPPL_4 (please compare the code furhter down)

Why can't I access the controls on the tabbed dialogs?

This was the suggestion of MinXin Yu:

m_wnd1.Create(IDD_PPL_1, &m_wndTab);

where the original code had:

m_wnd1.Create(IDD_PPL_1, this);

and "this" was a pointer to the form view and
&m_wndTab is a pointer to the tab control of type MFCTabCtrl.

Please check further down for the complete code!

Thank you everyone who helped!!!!

The following is the code, which leaves actually one question open, which is:
Why do I have to copy the control from the sample project in order to have a tabbed run time control.

```
    void CTabControlView::OnInitialUpdate()
    {
        // There is only one view ever, so it only needs to do the initial
        // update once--otherwise the application is  resized needlessly.
        static BOOL bUpdatedOnce = FALSE;
        if (bUpdatedOnce)
            return;
        bUpdatedOnce = TRUE;

        CFormView::OnInitialUpdate();
        GetParentFrame()->RecalcLayout();

        if (m_wndTab.GetSafeHwnd () != NULL)
            return;

        CRect rectTab;

        m_wndTabLoc.GetWindowRect (&rectTab);
        ScreenToClient (&rectTab);

        m_wndTab.Create (CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_3D, rectTab, this, 1, CMFCTabCtrl::LOCATION_TOP);
        // MinXin Wu suggested to replace "this" by "&m_wndTab"
        m_wnd1.Create(IDD_PPL_1, &m_wndTab); 

        // remove title bar of dialog
        m_wnd1.ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);

        // MinXin Wu suggested to replace "this" by "&m_wndTab"
        m_wnd2.Create(IDD_PPL_2, &m_wndTab);
        // remove title bar of dialog
        m_wnd2.ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);

        // MinXin Wu suggested to replace "this" by "&m_wndTab"
        m_wnd3.Create(IDD_PPL_3, &m_wndTab);

        // remove title bar of dialog
        m_wnd3.ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);

        // MinXin Wu suggested to replace "this" by "&m_wndTab"
        m_wnd4.Create(IDD_PPL_4, &m_wndTab);

        // remove title bar of dialog
        m_wnd4.ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);


        m_wndTab.AddTab (&m_wnd1, _T("One"), 0, FALSE);
        m_wndTab.AddTab (&m_wnd2, _T("Two"), 1, FALSE);
        m_wndTab.AddTab (&m_wnd3, _T("Three"), 2, FALSE);
        m_wndTab.AddTab (&m_wnd4, _T("Four"), 3, FALSE);
        UpdateData (FALSE);
        }
```

The CPPL_1 - CPPL_4 classes can be found in the question
Here is the header file for the form view!

```
    // This is a part of the Microsoft Foundation Classes C++ library.
    // Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation
    // All rights reserved.
    //
    // This source code is only intended as a supplement to the
    // Microsoft Foundation Classes Reference and related
    // electronic documentation provided with the library.
    // See these sources for detailed information regarding the
    // Microsoft Foundation Classes product.

    #pragma once
    #include "CPPL_1.h"
    #include "CPPL_2.h"
    #include "CPPL_3.h"
    #include "CPPL_4.h"
    class CTabControlView : public CFormView
    {
    protected: // create from serialization only
        CTabControlView();
        DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CTabControlView)

    public:
        enum { IDD = IDD_TABCONTROL_FORM };

    // Attributes
    public:
        CTabControlDoc* GetDocument();

    protected:
        CMFCTabCtrl m_wndTab;

    // Operations
    public:
        CPPL_1 m_wnd1;
        CPPL_2 m_wnd2;
        CPPL_3 m_wnd3;
        CPPL_4 m_wnd4;
        // Overrides
        public:
        virtual BOOL PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);
        protected:
        virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
        virtual void OnInitialUpdate(); // called first time after construct

    // Implementation
    public:
        virtual ~CTabControlView();
    #ifdef _DEBUG
        virtual void AssertValid() const;
        virtual void Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const;
    #endif

    protected:
        //void AddNotification (LPCTSTR lpszText);

    protected:
        afx_msg void OnContextMenu(CWnd*, CPoint point);

        DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    public:
        //afx_msg void OnCbnSelchangeTabStyle();
        //afx_msg void OnStnClickedTab();
        CStatic m_wndTabLoc;
        afx_msg void OnStnClickedTab();
        afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton1();
    };

    #ifndef _DEBUG  // debug version in TabControlView.cpp
    inline CTabControlDoc* CTabControlView::GetDocument()
       { return (CTabControlDoc*)m_pDocument; }
    #endif
```

Comment: Glad to know the suggestion work for you. You could click '✔' to accept the answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.